# Forward http to https on a folder in MAMP

Tags: apache, ssl, https, mamp

So I have created an SSL key and a certificate for my website. I was able to forward every page of my website to HTTPS by using the following code in my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

That works fine for every page, but I would like to be able to forward http to https only on my Account page. I tried this code in my `https-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com/Account
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>
# SSL Configuration
<VirtualHost *:443>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account"
      ServerName example.com
      ServerAlias www.example.com/Account
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key

</VirtualHost>
```

It does not redirect to https, it just stays the standard http. My Certificate is correct so that is not the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second condition to your rewriting, so that it only gets applied then that condition is true. This also allows you to extract the required part of the request:

```
# http Configuration
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Account
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website"
    <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website>
        [...]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# SSL Configuration
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website"
    <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website>
        [...]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still doesn't automatically switch to https. It throws this error in apache_error.log: [Sat Mar 21 10:32:30 2015] [error] [client 12.34.56.789] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account/Account. I think it is moving to far ahead in the path and can't find the folder. Any idea why?

Comment: Sure you are using the code above? I made a few adjustments over time, sorry for that. The error reads like you are using an older version

Comment: Used the exact code you used. The only thing I removed was the <Directory> tags, they cause apache to fail to start.  I didn't know if those were important or not.

Comment: They are required to place options that apply to those locations. obviously you have to replace the `[...]`, those were just placeholders. You can read about those tags in the excellent apache documentation. But leave them away for now. What url gets rewritten that leads to the error you posted?

Comment: As said: take a look into the documentation. That is what it  is there fore. It does not make sense if I repeat that here, you have to start reading that documentation anyway. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: I just realized the `ServerAlias` directives were nonsense. I fixed that above.

Comment: So I realized that the <Directory> tags were crashing apache because there was no </Directory> tag. Once I fixed that, I added the ServerAlias that you changed in the answer. I reloaded apache and still didn't auto redirect. So I went to www.example.com/Account and changed the URL to https://www.example.com/Account/ and it gave me 404 error. With the path that it couldn't find which was: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account/Account. Now I am extremely confused.

Comment: As noted in the answer the http server delivers _only_ the Accounts directory. So the additional `/accounts` in the url does not make sense. It should be just `https: // example.com/` Otherwise you have to change the configuration.

Comment: I changed the answer with the modifications mentioned above.

Comment: So I just entered you new code in and substituted my parameters for my website and now it let's me type in https://www.example.com/Account. But it doesn't automatically redirect from http to https if I type in www.example.com/Account.

Comment: Sorry, no idea, the code is correct now as far as I can see. Sure you always us a capital `A`? Remember: the internet is traditionally Unix country, not MS-Windows. So the web is case sensitive.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's a problem that only I can fix. Thanks so much for your help!